# The new help page - do we have link shortcuts?

Tags: support

I'm currently coming to grips with [the new help pages that replace the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center). I used to be able to reference the faq with `[faq]` - are there similar shortcuts for sections of the new help page?

Comment: You mean the `[faq#dontask]` kind of short links? [faq#dontask] does seem to work, but no idea about the rest.

Comment: Some of them still work - e.g. `[faq#promotion]` goes to the right page: [faq#promotion].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @dynamic's answer was correct at the time he answered (and I'll delete this if he updates), apparently some time in july, SE added magic links, including the old faq links. Seems to work for me

In addition to the old magic links also seem to work

- [help] -> /help (the help center landing page for whatever site you're on)
- [help/on-topic] links to "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic](/help/on-topic)
- [help/dont-ask] links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask)
- [meta-help] links to "What is meta?" [meta-help](/help/whats-meta)
- [help/behavior] links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" [help/behavior](/help/behavior)

[Taken from this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/135565).

Works for me I guess

Comment: [help] just doing a quick test myself... please ignore... [help/on-topic] what about [help/searching]... apparently not.  However, this is a pretty nifty thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Not yet.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183131/replace-faq-magiclink-with-help)

It seems like they're trying to decide how to implement the magic links since there are multiple pages in the help center (for example, should they have magic links for each individual help page).

Comment: Selected as the correct answer for now. I was kind of hoping we'd have a canonical list for reference tho :/